# Table captions for French not in consistent with List of tables using French in babel

Tags: tables, captions, babel

When I use a table captions with babel for French, it's appearing as `Table 1` rather than `Tableau 1`. My `\date` is formatted properly, and the `Liste des tableaux` is correct. Why is it <del>broken</del> inconsistent for table captions?

Here's my MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\title{Exemple avec tableau}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\listoftables

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Ceci n'est pas une table}
\label{table:1}
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result:

> [image]

Comment: Adding `\addto\captionsfrench{\def\tablename{Tableau}}` to the preamble should help.

Answer (score 3):

It is not broken, it is the default for table captions. If you insist to change it, here is how to do it with the new syntax:

```
\documentclass[french]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\def\frenchtablename{\scshape Tableau}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\title{Exemple avec tableau}
\author{René M. }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\listoftables

\raisebox{20ex}[0pt]{\parbox{\linewidth}{\epigraph{\raggedleft Ceci n’est pas une liste}{René M. }}}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Ceci n'est pas une table}
\label{table:1}
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c||}
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex]
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex]
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is the default for the caption (`Table`) different than the default title of `Liste des tableaux`? Something seems broken.

Comment: No real idea. Anyway, ‘Table’ is also used in French. Maybe because it lacks a signature? ;o)